# no tables used on EXPLAIN SELECT

Tags: mysql

I'm currently trying to find the most efficient way of finding the last record for each Group, in a table that has nearly 600M records.

The quickest way I've found is using a subquery but omitting the FROM clause in it:

````
```
EXPLAIN 
SELECT customer, server, disk 
FROM t1 
WHERE timestamp = (SELECT MAX(timestamp)) 
GROUP BY customer, server, disk;
```
````

But the `EXPLAIN` provides `No tables used` on the Subquery:

````
```
+------+--------------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type        | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows      | Extra                                        |
+------+--------------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-----------+----------------------------------------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY            | t1    | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 185093129 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|    2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | NULL  | NULL | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |      NULL | No tables used                               |
+------+--------------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-----------+----------------------------------------------+
```
````

The only other option is using `JOINS` or a Subquery with the `FROM` Clause; but both seem to be doing a whole table scan twice. Is there any issues with the method that I've described here?

Comment: Strange: I'd expect the query to thow an error. However - there are a lot of answers on SO solving your task.

Answer (score 0):

`(SELECT MAX(timestamp))` is a SUBQUERY with no table.

you can try thinks like this

```
SELECT @var:= MAX(timestamp) from t1;

SELECT customer, server, disk 
FROM t1 
WHERE timestamp =  @var
GROUP BY customer, server, disk;
```

or  (slower)

```
SELECT customer, server, disk 
FROM t1 
WHERE timestamp =  (SELECT  MAX(timestamp) from t1)
GROUP BY customer, server, disk;
```

Comment: This is what I was doing initially but because it can't make use of Indexes it's doing two table scans which is making the query really inefficient and slow.

Comment: why not add a index to `timestamp` ? it can solve the problem.

Comment: There is an index but unfortunately it still takes over an hour. I solved the problem, sort of, by limiting searching for the last record in the last 3 days which should suffice.

Now I have an issue with saving it as a View because there is a subquery.

Comment: the slower is the second or the first ?

Comment: They both take well over an hour; limiting to 3 days and it's done in about 20 seconds.